# Получить координаты объекта, который анимирован (javafx)

Tags: java, javafx, анимация

Как мне отслеживать координаты объекта, который находится в движении? Движение осуществляется таким способом: создаётся последовательность из нескольких линейных перемещений случайной длины и объединяются в одну последовательную анимацию.

```
// ну здесь ещё цикл с i задан
 for (int j = 0; j < rounds; j++) {
                transition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), horses[i]);
                double t = Math.random() * 70;
                transition.setByX(t);
                sequentialTransition.getChildren().add(transition);
                horses[i].setX(horses[i].getX()+t);
            }
            parallelTransition.getChildren().add(sequentialTransition);
```

При достижении определённого значения анимацию следует прервать. Пробовал привязаться через xPropetry, не удалось

```
  horses[i].xProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (newValue.doubleValue()>=100)
                    parallelTransition.pause();
            });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Оказывается, есть translateProperty